# How do I chop up a big picture into 2-3 pages?

Tags: images, printing

I have a really wide picture(technical design). Is there any GPL(or similar) licensed software for Windows XP that will auto-chop the picture so I can print it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never used it, but [this](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/) was on SourceForge and may help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the built-in image printing wizard in XP supports this.

**Edit**
Nevermind.  Just tested and it will only shrink to fit a page.

Comment: that'd be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in GIMP.  Not sure how "atuomated" you can get it.

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gimp-win/gimp-2.6.7-i686-setup.exe

Comment: Anything you can do in gimp you can script.  It's just not always easy to get the script right.